# Phase shift of the signal with grid frequency

Tags: phase-shift

I have to deal with a signal with grid frequency. And I have two channels, one channel should shift 90 with the other. Now, I have two ideas:

1. Use an AC integrator (actually it can only approximate 90 degree infinitely).
2. Use a one-order all-pass filter.

As known, the grid frequency may have some fluctuation, so which one is more insensitive to that? And are there any better solutions?

Comment: How important is it to maintain amplitude equality with frequency variations?

Comment: Yes, it should maintain amplitude equality in the grid frequency variation range. IMHO, from this point, choice 2 is better.

Comment: Neither will do what you appear to want. The integrator will not provide amplitude equality with changes in frequency and the all-pass filter will not provide a constant 90 degrees for a change in frequency.

Comment: Digitise, delay, output - with the delay tied into the period of signal.  A micro controller solution.

Comment: You might try the average of an integrator and a differentiator (inverting one, of course).

Comment: How much frequency variation do you have to deal with? If not too much you may be able to integrate it to get a 90 degree phase shift and feed   that into multiplier. Take your output from tthe multiplier but also peak rectify it to get the amplitude, you can use this as the other input  to the multiplier for a gain control